# Ideal Gas Equation Assumptions

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics, kinematics, ideal-gas, gas

The two assumptions are that the gases are points of mass that move, they have no volume and that there is no interaction between other molecules.

But even the points of mass can collide with each other so wouldn't that be considered interaction between molecules?

Answer (score 2):

By no interactions they mean no intermolecular attraction forces (van der Waal forces). In other words the internal energy of an ideal gas is all kinetic and no potential energy. In addition collisions between molecules and with the walls that contain them are considered perfectly elastic, so that both kinetic energy and momentum are conserved.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For an ideal gas, the molecules move under the [assumptions of kinetic theory](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/kinthe.html#c1) - elastic collisions with no other forces acting between them, much like smooth billiard balls. You could refer to these collisions as *some form of interaction*, but the details of the interaction are unknown and irrelevant for the theory.

Answer (score 0):

Actually assumptions, on which kinetic theory of gases are based, are a little bit different than you stated. (Ideal Gas Law was derived from kinetic theory of gases). Basic assumptions are these :

- $N_V \gg 1 \,\,\to$ number of molecules in a volume is VERY big
- $\frac {V_{\text{molecule}}}{V_{\text{gas}}} \ll 1 \,\,\to$ molecule volume is negligible compared to volume of gases, but actually this assumption can be derived from a first one
- $\frac {E_{k}}{E_{k} + U} \approx 1 \,\,\to$ molecule total energy is it's kinetic energy due to elastic collisions between particles. Other forms of interactions are negligible, thus any form of potential energy of molecule is assumed to be $U=0$

There are more of assumptions used, you can read it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases#Assumptions).

Answer (score 0):

Collisions are not all the possible interactions: think e.g. of van der Waals forces, that cause attraction between the particles of the gas. So by no interactions we mean that there are no forces between the particles $\Leftrightarrow$ potential energy is considered constant (and usually set to zero) all across the system.

PS: apart from very peculiar setups, material points have null probability to collide one with another, so it is safe to use them as a model for the particles of an ideal gas.